# Github changes lost accidentally

Tags: git, github

I was working since 10 hours on an iOS application. 5 minutes ago i accidentally pressed cmd+S on github software instead of xcode. Activity indicator showed up and all changed files greyed out. I was unable to see changes in files. Updated files were still there in "Changes" section. I then made a commit. Progress bar filled up and commit was successfully done (i guess). Once i moved to "History" section in github software, there was no such commit in "History" section.
Please help!

Comment: You might need to do a git push for the changes to reflect.

Comment: i did that. unfortunately nothing happened.

Comment: Does saving inside the git software, cause the files to be set back to the last state of the git commit?

Comment: @亚历山大 in toolbar menu it says cmd+S is for "Sync"

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem, the sync button should save your changes and pull remote changes to your local git:

> The sync button pushes your changes to GitHub and pulls down other’s changes in one operation, letting you quickly share local changes.

[Description](https://mac.github.com/)

Maybe you are looking at the wrong branch?